# Do characters tend to get used for a while nowadays, or disposed of and replaced regularly?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, player-characters

When I was in high school, a long time ago, kids talked about their characters lasting and up-leveling for so long that they reached high enough levels to get to send them away to Wizards of the Coast for stamping as 'demi-god'.  I'm not sure that's true.  But, it suggests that back then, people kept their characters for quite a while.

I haven't really been in an RPG campaign since then.  I want to get back into it.  I'm looking forward to rolling a character, working him up the levels for the next 5 years or so, and ending up with a badass.

I've been trying to find out peoples' attitudes around how long they stick with their characters nowadays, and from the limited research I've been doing, it seems like characters these days are a disposable, one-campaign thing, at least in D&D.

Is that really the case these days? What's it like in D&D 5e? Do people tend to stick around with their characters for a while or replace them regularly? Will I have a chance of doing what I want to do with my character?

Comment: 1. How do the answers to [Is it common for D&D characters be moved to or reused in different DMs' campaigns?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56041/is-it-common-for-dd-characters-be-moved-to-or-reused-in-different-dms-campaign) not answer this as well?  2. This seems even more loosely defined in terms of what would make a best answer than your previous question.  If you just want people to randomly discuss their experiences this isn't the best venue.  Consider editing your question to where there's criteria for an objectively best answer.

Comment: @mxyzplk On first point, it's not obvious that the other question answers this one unless you've already read the other one's answers to find out, and you wouldn't know to do that unless you'd already read them. You're right that there's no way to answer this objectively, though.

Comment: You may note that the guy asking this question is the guy who asked the other one.  That's what we like to call a "context clue."